# Can we send email with auto populated field in email HTML body using SPD workflow

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, email

I want to send the email using SPD workflow where email body is HTML and should only display the rows which have data and hide the remaining rows.

The challenge I am facing is : I can set the HTML table inside email body using the string builder but it's the static table with static rows. How can we make the table rows dynamic on run time and only show the rows which have data and leave the remaining.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not enough info for a detailed answer, but you can use the Set Workflow Variable action to build the string with the HTML and the data as a workflow variable, and then use that variable in the email body.

Comment: Thanks.... it worked, I have set a  workflow variable and saved the HTML in it. Then called the variable  in the Email body and it worked as expected.